# How to find any variable word in a String with Regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

Example String:

```
Here are sample apartment pictures {img="/path/photo1.jpg" alt="I am Photo Title"} and {img="/path/photo2.jpg" alt="I am Photo Title #2"} this...
```

They must be found:

```
{img="/path/photo1.jpg" alt="I am Photo Title"}
{img="/path/photo2.jpg" alt="I am Photo Title 2"}
```

How can these image links be found in sentences?

Comment: Have you tried on regex101 or similar?

Comment: Yes, `regex` should help you with some Google results for that. Did you run into specific issues with anything?

Comment: @Andreas I guess that you gave a down score. I do not know how to use Regex therefore I ask quesiton

Comment: This is one of many solutions: https://regex101.com/r/TMvLUT/1

Comment: You can use regex to solve a lot problems, but a lot of the time there are better solutions. In this case going through the string with strpos looking for {img= and then look for a matching } and parse everything in between would be a lot more efficient.

Comment: I have not downvoted

Comment: If you don't know how to use Regex, but you want to use it, then you need to learn it. It's that simple. If you still have a problem, after you've learned it, or you don't understand something, you can ask a question on SO. The idea is: At least show us that you've tried to solve your problem yourself, don't be lazy. This might be the reason for the downvote. I also didn't downvote your question. Downvoters usually don't comment.

Comment: @ScallioXTX Not. The Zend VM and its string function calls (and often required loops) are pretty much always *less* efficient then the PCRE VM - which just so happens to be designed for string processing. (Not to speak of the code overhead.)

Comment: @mario I benchmarked it, and indeed preg_match is faster in this case (by a factor of ~2.5). I learned something! :) Nevertheless, tokenizing would be a better way to solve it than regex imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$string = "Here are sample apartment pictures {img='/path/photo1.jpg' alt='I am Photo Title'} and {img='/path/photo2.jpg' alt='I am Photo Title #2'} this...";

preg_match_all("/({([\w]+)[^}]*})(.*?)/", $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $val) {
    echo "Variable Word In String: " . $val[1] . "<br>\n";
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with explode also.
Here I explode on "{" first then remove items in array not starting with "img=".
Then I explode on "}" to remove the excess on the right.

Just as an alternative to regex, not saying it's better than regex or strpos ways to do it.

```
$str ='Here are sample apartment pictures {img="/path/photo1.jpg" alt="I am Photo Title"} and {img="/path/photo2.jpg" alt="I am Photo Title #2"} this...';

$arr = explode("{", $str);
Foreach($arr as $key => &$val){
    if(substr($val,0,4) == "img="){
        $val = "{". explode("}", $val)[0] . "}";
    }else{
        Unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}
Var_dump($arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/7Zov0